# why doesn't pygments discover my custom lexer after installation

Tags: python, plugins, setuptools, lexer, pygments

i've developed and tested a custom pygments lexer, as described [here](https://pygments.org/docs/lexerdevelopment/)...  i then prepared a `pyproject.toml` file whose contents are as follows:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "my-lexer"
version = "0.0.1"
dependencies = ["Pygments"]

[pygments.lexers]
dummy = "pkg.mylexer:MyLexer"
```

i then `python -m build` the project and `pip install dist/*.tar.gz` the generated output....  using `pip list`, i can see both pygments and my own package installed in the same environment....

as a test, i'll run `pygmentize -L` but don't see my custom language listed; attempts to force use of the lexer through the `-l` option likewise fail....

is there some obvious step i'm missing????  when/how does pygments discover my plugin???  is there some way i can trace that discovery process???

Answer (score 0):

the group `[pygments.lexers]` should have been named `[project.entry-points."pygments.lexers"]`

all is well....